# sudo apt-get update - error 404 on 16.04

Tags: 16.04, apt, updates, ppa

I am using Ubuntu 16.04

When I run the command `sudo apt-get update`, I get a 404 Error on two packages from PPAs (fossfreedom and nesthib).

How might I correct these problems?

[image]

Comment: Check your internet connection. Have you modified the sources settings, or the firewall settings?

Comment: Two of your PPAs aren't working properly. (fossfreedom and nesthib) They have an i386 release file, but not an amd64 one, indicating that your processor architecture is not supported. (I think... I could be that the are actually just misconfigured.)

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have added other repositories besides the default sources from Ubuntu. If you can guarantee that your Internet connection is working and the problem persists, then I believe that there is something wrong with these repositories. Maybe they are temporally off-line or your firewall or proxy is blocking them.

One way to partially solve this problem is to restore the default repositories. First, make sure to backup your current apt configuration files

```
$ cd /etc/apt 
$ sudo cp sources.list sources.list.old
$ sudo cp -r sources.list.d sources.list.d.old
```

Now, make sure that /etc/apt/sources.list only has the following content:

```
deb http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
deb-src http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted

deb http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
deb-src http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted

deb http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb-src http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe
deb-src http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe

deb http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
deb-src http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
deb http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse
deb-src http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse

deb http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse

deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
```

Then, remove everything from /etc/apt/sources.list.d

```
$ sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
```

Finally, update and see what happens:

```
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

If everything works fine, you will be able to upgrade the packages from the standard Ubuntu distribution.